# Google Play Console Контент для продажи

Tags: консоль

у меня такой вопрос можно ли в приложении делать меняющие цены в зависимости от какого то значения к Примеру : **1230 \ 5 = 246**       **(246р)** это и есть цена.
Дело в том что в **Google Play Console** Контент для продажи должен быть заранее установлен а заранее я его не знаю ???